# Get Index of Array containing Structs by searching for Struct Value using Swift 3.0

Tags: swift

I have a struct for holding data;

```
struct MyStruct {
  var age: Int
  var name: String
}
```

I make an array of this and fill it with data;

```
var myArray = [MyStruct]()
myArray[0] = MyStruct(age: 26, name: "John")
myArray[1] = MyStruct(age: 35, name: "Smith")
```

How can I find the index of the element in `myArray` that contains the name "Smith"?

Edit: Here's more context about where I need to find the location using the new code from Losiowaty;

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
  let selection = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.textLabel
  let name = selection!.text!
  let location = myArray.index(where: { $0.name == name})

  //additional code to comply with the function and return, unneeded for this context
}
```

Comment: 1) Class/struct names should start with uppercase letters. 2) Why do you initialize `age` and `name` in your `myStruct` to useless values? 3) Why is `myArray` initialized with an empty `myStruct`?

Comment: 1) Updated, my bad.
2) I'm not sure what you mean, the struct is just defining the data that's going to be stored, so when I add data later (the hard coded data is just an example, it will be based on user input in the final product).
3) I was defining the array as an array of myStruct() so data can be added later. I'll be using `myArray.append` based on user input later.

Comment: 2) I'm referring to the unneeded `= Int()` and `= String()` on the two properties. 3) You want `[MyStruct]`, not `[MyStruct()]`. The first declares an empty array that will contain instances of `MyStruct`. The seconds declares an array containing one instance of `MyStruct`.

Comment: Alright fixed again.

Comment: Looks good now. Does the answer by Losiowaty work now after making those changes?

Comment: It did not start working after these changes, but the changes cleared other issues elsewhere in my code so thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `index(where:)` method. A quick example :

```
let index = myArray.index(where: { $0.name == "Smith" })
```

In a case when there would be no such element, the method will return `nil`.

With more context from edits, the best (i.e. safest) way would be something like this :

```
if let name = selection?.name {
    if let location = myArray.index(where: { $0.name == name }) {
        // you know that location is not nil here
    }
}
```

Source - https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688966-index

Comment: I gave it a go and I'm getting an error:
`Ambiguous reference to member '=='`

Comment: Strange, since this would be basic string comparison. Are you sure you didn't do `$0 == "Smith"`?

Comment: I left out some nuance to my actual code when I converted it to generic code. When I'm doing the find, I'm passing the name to be searched for as a stored variable `let name = selection!.text`.

Comment: Ah, is this `name` an optional by chance? If so you simply need to unwrap it.

Comment: `name` is unwrapped when it's created. Please see my up updated edit! Thank you for the help so far.

Comment: @kingfoot No, `name` is not unwrapped. The `text` property is optional therefore `name` is optional.

Comment: As rmaddy said, `selection` is in fact unwrapped, but its `text` property is not. You'd need to use it like this - `let name = selection!.name!` to have them both unwrapped in the same line.

Comment: Alright updated it with an additional unwrap; `let name = selection!.text!` but the error is still there.

Comment: Eventually got there. Rookie mistake on my part, wasn't using the correct value in my array for the comparison. It's working now, thank you so much! I went further into it and I'm understanding now. Also a big thanks to @maddy for the additional help.

Answer (score 5):

**For Swift 4:**  index(where:) has been deprecated, so now use firstIndex:

```
let index = firstIndex(where: { $0.name == "Smith" })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath:     IndexPath) {
    let MyStruct = myArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.yourLable?.text = MyStruct.name
       }
```